# Async await is blocking other function from running

Tags: javascript, node.js

So my two functions reside in their own files, the app is made up of four functions all async await, first it grabs info, then installs then zips the info and finally supposed to post using axios. From the server.js indeed every operation is carried out but nothing under the await zipFunction() in my axios function runs, not even console.log(). Please help

Code
AXIOS FILE

```
const axios = require("axios");
const fs = require('fs');

const path = require('path')
const { pathToFileURL } = require("url");

const zippedFile = require('./archiver')

//Make POST
async function makeAxios(){
  await zippedFile()

  console.log("AXIOS!!!")

  user = "";
  pwd = "";
  ZipPath = path.join(__dirname, '')

  console.log(ZipPath)
  axios({
    
    method: 'POST',
    url: "",
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/zip'
    },
    auth: {
        username: user,
        password: pwd
    },
    maxContentLength: Infinity,
    maxBodyLength: Infinity,
    data: fs.createReadStream(ZipPath),
  });


}

module.exports = {makeAxios}
```

ZIP FILE

```
//Modules
const archiver = require("archiver");
const fs = require("fs");

//Locals
const packagedModules = require("./packagedModules");
const { branch } = require("./getRepo");
const path = require("path");
const { resolve } = require("path");

const archive = archiver("zip");

async function makeZip() {
  await packagedModules();
  
  const output = fs.createWriteStream(`${branch}.zip`);
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    output.on(
      "close",
      function () {
        console.log(archive.pointer() + " total bytes");
        console.log(
          "archiver has been finalized and the output file descriptor has closed."
        );
      },
      archive.pipe(output),
      archive.directory(
        path.join(__dirname, ""),
        false
      ),
      archive.directory("subdir/", "new-subdir"),
      archive.finalize()
    );
  });

}

module.exports = makeZip;
```

Comment: You are returning a new Promise, but never calling `resolve`. You need to call `resolve` and `reject` accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Promise returned by `makeZip` is never resolved or rejected.

When creating a new Promise, you receive two arguments: `resolve` and `reject`.
One of these arguments must be called, otherwise your promise will never finalize.

Try calling `resolve()` within your close callback function.

```js
return new Promise((resolve) => {
  output.on('close', function() {
    resolve();
  });
});
```

Read more about Promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#chained_promises